# sharedPref.getInt: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, android

I have a `preferences.xml` which contains the following definition:

```
<ListPreference
    android:title="@string/LimitSetting"
    android:summary="@string/LimitSettingText"
    android:key="limitSetting"
    android:defaultValue="10"
    android:entries="@array/limitArray"
    android:entryValues="@array/limitValues" />
```

and with values defined as follows:

```
<string-array name="limitArray">
    <item>1 %</item>
    <item>3 %</item>
    <item>5 %</item>
    <item>10 %</item>
    <item>20 %</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="limitValues">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>20</item>
</string-array>
```

which is being called in an activity as follows:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
int offsetProgressInitial = sharedPref.getInt("limitSetting", 10);
```

So far so good, but when the code gets actually called I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:239)
at com.test.app.NewEntryActivity.onCreate(NewEntryActivity.java:144)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5977)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2258)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2365) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
```

This error does not make any sense to me. The list only contain values that can be converted into an int, and the default values given in the xml file and in the code also represents just a number. So why do I get this error, and how to fix it?

Comment: For your limitValues does it allow you to use an `integer-array` instead?

Comment: Ah it does. The tutorial I used must have missed this tiny bit of very important infprmation... What do I have to change on the xml file then? Ins' the value still a string: `android:defaultValue="10"`?

Comment: Good question. Try it out and see if it works. Maybe you still can't use integer-array.

Comment: I still get the same error even with an integer-array...

Comment: It was worth a shot...I posted an answer that should work for you.

Comment: My mistake was that I changed from saveString() to saveInt() and started the app with old sharedPreferences, so just had to uninstall the app and reinstall, voila it worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at what `getInt()` does internally you will see the problem:

```
Integer v = (Integer)mMap.get(key);
```

Your key "limitSetting" is returning a `String` which cannot be cast to an Integer.

You can parse it yourself however:

```
int offsetProgressInitial = Integer.parseInt(sharedPref.getString("limitSetting", "10"));
```

Comment: That works - but does that mean the class `SharedPreferences` has a bug? Or is the method `getInt` just for decoration or to confuse android beginners?

Comment: It is not a bug and by design although it can be confusing. If you look at the documentation for the method it says, "Throws ClassCastException if there is a preference with this name that is not an int."

Comment: However, if `getInt` does not work with an `integer-array`, how to use `getInt` at all? There must be a case when I could use `getInt`, otherwise, if I have only can get a string which I need to convert, a method named `getInt` does not make any sense...

Comment: Are you sure it was failing in the same location and not somewhere else when you tried `integer-array`? You were probably right when you said it won't like the `android:defaultValue="10"` with an `integer-array` in use.

Comment: But when defining `android:defaultValue=10` without the quotes it does not work either.

Comment: There is a long time issue reported on this...https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2096

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101718/discussion-between-alex-and-george-mulligan).

Answer (score 1):

First let's have a look at SharedPreferences.getInt() method.

**public abstract int getInt (String key, int defValue)**

- Added in API level 1
- Retrieve an int value from the preferences.

**Parameters**

1. **key** : The name of the preference to retrieve.
2. **defValue** :  Value to return
       if this preference does not exist.

**Returns** : Returns the preference value if it exists, or defValue. 
**Throws** ClassCastException **if there is a preference with this name that is not an int.**

So in your case, all the entry values have been defined as a string array. Therefore the class cast exception will be thrown.

You can simply solve this problem by modifying your code as follows.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
int offsetProgressInitial = Integer.parseInt(sharedPref.getString("limitSetting", "10"));
```

Comment: The documentation seems to be incorrect. I still get the error, even when I use `getInt` and I specify an `integer-array` instead of a `string-array` in the `array.xml`.

Comment: Let me reproduce the issue and check.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if `putInt` was never called then `getInt` will return a null value, even if you set a default integer value.

This seems to be a bug that was never fixed. So the solution is to call the `putInt` before calling `getInt`.