# java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I've been lurking here for answers but I can't seem to find what's wrong with my code. I have a program that counts the Lifecycle activities of Android. Every time I run it I get this error when I try to retrieve data on the onCreate() method.

```
private TextView numCreate;
private TextView numStart;
private TextView numResume;
private TextView numPause;
private TextView numStop;
private TextView numDestroy;

private int numc= 0;
private int nums= 0;
private int numr= 0;
private int nump= 0;
private int numst=0;
private int numd= 0;

private String pref  = "MYPREFERENCES";

private String CREATE_NUM_KEY  = "CREATE_NUM_KEY";
private String START_NUM_KEY   = "START_NUM_KEY";
private String RESUME_NUM_KEY  = "RESUME_NUM_KEY";
private String PAUSE_NUM_KEY   = "PAUSE_NUM_KEY";
private String STOP_NUM_KEY    = "STOP_NUM_KEY";
private String DESTROY_NUM_KEY = "DESTROY_NUM_KEY";



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lifecycle);

    numCreate= findViewById(R.id.ocreateview);
    logContainer= findViewById(R.id.logContainer);

    sharedPref= getSharedPreferences(pref,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    numc = sharedPref.getInt(CREATE_NUM_KEY,0);
    nums = sharedPref.getInt(START_NUM_KEY,0);
    numr = sharedPref.getInt(RESUME_NUM_KEY,0);
    nump = sharedPref.getInt(PAUSE_NUM_KEY,0);
    numst = sharedPref.getInt(STOP_NUM_KEY,0);
    numd = sharedPref.getInt(DESTROY_NUM_KEY,0);

    numStart.setText(getNum(nums));
    numResume.setText(getNum(numr));
    numPause.setText(getNum(nump));
    numStop.setText(getNum(numst));
    numDestroy.setText(getNum(numd));


    logContainer.append("Triggered onCreate()!");
    logContainer.append("\n\r");


    numc++;
    numCreate.setText(getNum(numc));
    String tstamp = timestamp();
    tCreate.setText(tstamp);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

    editor.putInt(CREATE_NUM_KEY, numc);

    editor.commit();
    editor.apply();
}
```

the error points on the line "numc = sharedPref.getInt(CREATE_NUM_KEY,0);" with the message "java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer". Thank you

Comment: the error means that you saved a `String` for the key `CREATE_NUM_KEY` and you are trying to retrieve it as an `int` (`Integer`)

Comment: Check the declaration of `getInt`. It probably takes 2 integers in param, and you give him 1 string, 1 integer

Comment: Have you ever stored it as string ? If yes, try reinstalling.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35022341/7482319) solution.

Comment: int getInt (String key, int defValue) this is what;s in the API that's why I'm wondering why it gives me an error.

Comment: error could be because the sharedPref.getInt(CREATE_NUM_KEY,0); is unable to convert the value it finds into integer. check value which gets fetched by this. Also, trying using sharedPref.getString(..) to check what values is being returned

Answer (score 0):

Method `getSharedPreferences()` returns `SharedPreferences` which is basically a `Map` and a `Map` contains keys and values and in the case of `SharedPreferences` the value can be anything, meaning it doesn't have to be an `int`. Looks like the value for key `CREATE_NUM_KEY` is a `String` and not an `Integer`. What makes you think it is an `Integer`?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error in Kotlin: `java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getInt`.
The reason for the error in my case was there were duplicated `SharedPreference` keys; one of which was represented as `String` type value.  So when I tried to access the SharedPreference Map `Int` key, the duplicated `String` key was being cast to the expected `Int` causing the error. E.g.:

```
val PREFS_BASE_DIR = "com.example.example"
val PREFS_FILENAME = "$PREFS_BASE_DIR.utils.prefs"
private val CREATE_NUM_KEY = "CREATE_NUM_KEY"
private val CREATE_START_KEY = "CREATE_NUM_KEY"  // Duplicate key

private val prefs: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

var num: String
        get() = prefs.getString(CREATE_NUM_KEY, "") ?: ""
        set(value) = prefs.edit().putString(CREATE_NUM_KEY, value).apply()
var start: Int
        get() {
            return prefs.getInt(CREATE_START_KEY,0)
        }
        set(value) = prefs.edit().putInt(CREATE_START_KEY, value!!).apply()
```

Not seeing the same error in your code.  But it is something that can creep up on you.